# Datetime to timestamp (year 1) raises ValueError

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

## Goal

I want to convert a `datetime.datetime` object to a timestamp.

## Code and output

```py
from datetime import datetime

dt1: datetime = datetime(year=2023, month=1, day=6)
ts1: int = dt1.timestamp()
# > 1672959600.0
dt2: datetime = datetime(year=1, month=1, day=2)
ts2: int = dt2.timestamp()
# > -62135510961.0
dt3: datetime = datetime(year=1, month=1, day=1)
ts3: int = dt3.timestamp()
# > Traceback (most recent call last):
# >   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
# > ValueError: year 0 is out of range
```

## Issue

I don't understand why this error is raised. This error also is raised when trying to set a `datetime.datetime` object's `year` attribute to `0` (`dt: datetime = datetime(year=0, ...)`), which is here expected.
Does someone have an explanation for this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you use naive datetime (you do not set a timezone), so that object represents *local time*. To calculate Unix time, UTC datetime needs to be determined based on given naive datetime. Depending on the timezone setting of the machine you run this on, that UTC datetime could lie before 0001-01-01 00:00:00 (if your timezone is ahead of UTC). Year 1 is the [minimum year](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.MINYEAR), therefore the error.

No issues if you set tz to UTC:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timezone

dt3: datetime = datetime(year=1, month=1, day=1, tzinfo=timezone.utc)
ts3: int = dt3.timestamp()
print(ts3)
# -62135596800.0
```

Answer (score -1):

> Does someone have an explanation for this?

There was not [year zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_zero) in European calendars

> A year zero does not exist in the Anno Domini (AD) calendar year
> system commonly used to number years in the Gregorian calendar (nor in
> its predecessor, the Julian calendar); in this system, the year 1 BC
> is followed directly by year AD 1.(...)

Comment: This doesn't explain why `datetime(year=1, month=1, day=1)` is assumed to be `year=0` for creation of a `timestamp`.

Comment: I've added a precision, as I've seen how my question could've been misunderstood. As @MisterMiyagi said, my question refers to the behavior when `year=1`